# Build Android with Superuser

Tags: android, root, android-source

Does anyone know how to include super-user privileges when building android from source (AOSP)?

Comment: Do you mean superuser privilege in the shell or in android apps?

Comment: @m-ricwhat if i want to compile Android with super user previliges for my android apps? is it possible? Basically i want an application to read or write into /system directory. Is it possible? I know it needs rooting. But to avoid the issues i thought it is better to build the android itself. Since its a reference board and we are testing something on it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get a root(ed) shell, edit `system/core/rootdir` or the init.rc associated to your device (e.g. `device/ti/panda/init.rc` for pandaboard) in android sources, and change those lines:

```
service console /system/bin/sh
    class core
    console
    disabled
    user shell
    group log
```

into:

```
service console /system/bin/sh
    class core
    console
    disabled
    user root 
    group root
```

To embed Superuser.apk in AOSP, you have to fetch and build:

1. [su-binary](https://github.com/ChainsDD/su-binary) (e.g. in `external/`) and stub/remove `system/extras/su` package.
2. [Superuser](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser) (e.g. in `packages/app/`)

You may also have to set the sticky bit of `/system/xbin/su` in su-binary/Android.mk. For instance, I used following makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := su
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := su.c db.c activity.cpp

SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libsqlite
ifeq ($(PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION),4)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSU_LEGACY_BUILD
    SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libandroid_runtime
else
    SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libcutils libbinder libutils
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
endif

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/sqlite/dist

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES)

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)


SU_INSTALL_DIR := $(TARGET_OUT)/xbin
SU_BINARY := $(SU_INSTALL_DIR)/su
# taken from busybox-android
$(SU_BINARY)-post: su
    @echo "Setting SUID/GUID to su-binary..."
    chmod ug+s $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)/su

SU_CMD := su
SYMLINKS := $(addprefix $(TARGET_OUT_EXECUTABLES)/,$(SU_CMD))
$(SYMLINKS): $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE) $(SU_BINARY)-post $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk
    @echo "Symlink: $@ -> /system/xbin/$(SU_CMD)"
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @rm -rf $@
    @ln -sf /system/xbin/$(SU_CMD) $@

ALL_DEFAULT_INSTALLED_MODULES += $(SU_BINARY)-post $(SYMLINKS)

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Is that possible to just embed Superuser.apk in AOSP? I want to add root permission to a APK (prebuilt / preinstalled).

Comment: Superuser.apk and SuperSU.apk require the su binary to be changed (contained in the zip file): http://superuserdownload.com/. Just embedding the apk won't be enough. To be specific to just one app, read this: http://su.chainfire.eu/#how

Comment: su-binary doesn't list jelly bean.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde try the version closest to JellyBean, I expect it to work just fine.

Comment: The attached mk of `su-binary` doesn't build. It says that there's a missing separator in  `$(SU_BINARY)-post:`

Comment: Also how do I create a key `build/target/product/security/superuser.pk8` for the superuser app?

Comment: What do you mean with "stub/remove system/extras/su package" in 1.? Replace the directory-content with the sources from the link? And why did you say "may also have to set the sticky bit"? Is it required or not?

Comment: Is this answer still valid for AOSP 7 ? I can not find the specified phrase! @shlatchz

Comment: @Saleh probably not. I haven't worked with AOSP for a while.

Comment: If you want to build AOSP with root access, (i.e. to be able to run adb root) just set target as userdebug. (in lunch command) @Bayou

Comment: Anyhow I am not sure but think the answer is valid still, if you need your apps to be able to run root commands

Comment: I have the same error of @shlatchz Have you fixed it ?