# Create a socket in android code(not in android application) getting Permission Denied

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-emulator

I am trying to open a socket in the android source code. Specifically, right now, I am in the DisplayDevice.cpp file, but the location of the socket code may change. Right now after I do:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

fd gets returned as -1, and when i check the error message it is listed as Permission Denied. I have looked around a lot for this, most answers involve adding the internet permission to the AndroidManifest file. This will *not* work for me as the code I am adding is inside of the android source code.

I was wondering if there is a way to bypass the permission denied. Or if there is a better way to do this/ a different type of socket to use(right now I am using sockets from

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, you may want to mark this as a C or C++ question. This is pretty much BSD-style sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite natural that you get `Permission Denied` error. This is simply because you don't have correct permission :). Check out [android permission model](http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html#the-android-permission-model-accessing-protected-apis)!

Imagine a scenario like a normal user in an operating system and you write a program which tries to open a socket like yours. You would most probably face the same problem, depending on where the named socket is to be created.

As you are trying to create the socket in [DisplayDevice.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/27e2562868dcd3ad26f9b4677b64ae272941704e/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayDevice.cpp) (compiling android from the source), you may be interested in compiling the source as a superuser. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624051/782094) is a solution posted by [m-ric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808044/m-ric) (I have never tested it).

Some useful pointers/references in similar direction and which I found useful during research on this enthralling topic are:

1. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-build-compile-su-from-source
2. execv command => http://code.google.com/p/superuser/source/browse/trunk/su/su.c?r=2#169
3. https://github.com/ChainsDD/su-binary
4. http://e2e.ti.com/support/omap/f/849/p/178679/648158.aspx#648158
5. A video from Google I/O 2011 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yorhsSPFG4

Comment: Thank you. This has really helped me to get started on the right direction. I am still looking for a more clear response as I am confused exactly what is going on and what is supposed to happen in the m-ric solution. All the same, this has been really helpful information to move forward.