# How do I get root access in Android while building from source?

Tags: android, root, android-source, selinux

I have built an Android version for Intel x86_64 from the [Intel Celadon source code](https://01.org/projectceladon/). The generated Android image is running on my machine. However, I do not have root access in the Terminal app in the Android device. I don't want the `adb shell`. I need the root access (`sudo`) in the Android Terminal app. How can I get that?

In previous Android builds, it was done by changing the `init.rc` as described in this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597139/build-android-with-superuser). However, this process does not work anymore because of SELinux update in Android. My guess is that there is some `capability` specification added. Can anybody give any clue on how to build Android from source to give `root` or `sudo` access in a Terminal app?